# Format for calling a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, double

I have very limited experience with Java, and I am having trouble implementing a bunch of classes I got from another source.

I am trying to use the calculateMutualInformation() from the following Java package: https://github.com/Craigacp/JavaMI

The associated java doc describes the method as follows:

```
public static double calculateMutualInformation(double[] firstVector,
                                            double[] secondVector)
```

If you want to see the doc file, it is available here: http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pococka4/JavaMI/index.html
I'm trying to pass two arrays into this function, using the following code in DoubleTrouble.java:

```
package JavaMI;
 public class DoubleTrouble { 
  public static double calculateMutualInformation()
  {
   double[] firstVector = {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0};
   double[] secondVector = {1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2};
   //return ??
  }
 }
```

The above data is just a place holder, however, I seem not to understand how to call this method. I get a missing return error, and any type of return statement I try to put in gives an error (mostly that I am missing a ".class"). I have also tried to put variables as parameters for the method, but that tends to give more errors.

Is there something wrong with the method, or the man (me)? I've also tried calling other methods from the package, like MutualInformation(), again to no avail. Also, I should mention that I compiled all the java files in the JavaMI package; not sure if that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`public static double calculateMutualInformation()`

- `public`: means the methods is visible from anywhere
- `static`: means no need to have an instance to call the method, i.e. `DoubleTrouble.calculateMutualInformation()` is allowed
- `double`: means the method returns a `double`

Another example:

```
// returns a double
public double sum(double a, double b) { return a+b; } 

// doesn't return anything
public void something(double a, double b) { System.out.println(a+b); }
```

See also [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) on method definitions

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to implement must accept 2 parameters:

`double[] firstVector` and `double[] secondVectory`

What you are currently doing is creating those two variables - which is wrong. Rather than create them in your method, your method *receives* them as parameters and then uses them to compute and return some `double` value which would look like so:

```
double mutualInformation = ... // compute for firstVector and secondVector

return mutualInformation;
```

Your method definition should look more like this:

```
public static double calculateMutualInformation(double[] firstVector, double[] secondVector) {
    double mutualInfo = ... // compute from firstVector and secondVector

    return mutualInfo; // returning type double as method head states
}
```